# How can I create a 3-bit counter gshare branch predictor out of a 2-bit counter gshare branch predictor?

Tags: c, architecture, counter, branch-prediction

I've been trying to figure out which parts of this code involve the 2-bit counter, because I have to make it into a 3-bit counter.

For the GSHARE_SIZE table size, I think the correct size for a 3-bit counter would be 17 instead of the 2-bit 18, because there is one more counter and 18 is too large for for the allocated memory space (64k).

Additionally, I believe the counter in the ---//update predictor--- section needs to be changed from:

```
            // update predictor
            bool t = uop->br_taken;
            if (t && gtable[gidx] < 1)
                gtable[gidx] ++;
            else if (!t && gtable[gidx] > -2)
                gtable[gidx] --;
```

to

```
            // update predictor
            bool t = uop->br_taken;
            if (t && gtable[gidx] < 2)
                gtable[gidx] ++;
            else if (!t && gtable[gidx] > -3)
                gtable[gidx] --;
```

Besides, these two things, I'm unsure of how to change this 2-bit counter into a 3-bit counter. Below is the code for the 2-bit predictor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

using namespace std;
#include "cbp3_def.h"
#include "cbp3_framework.h"

#define GSHARE_SIZE 18 // 256K 2-bit counters = 64 KB cost

// predictor tables
int8_t   *gtable;

// cost: depending on predictor size
uint32_t brh_fetch;
uint32_t brh_retire;

// count number of runs
uint32_t runs;

void PredictorInit() {
    runs = 0;
    gtable = new int8_t[1 << GSHARE_SIZE];
    assert(gtable);
}

void PredictorReset() {
    // this function is called before EVERY run
    // it is used to reset predictors and change configurations
        printf("Predictor:gshare\nconfig: %i counters, %i KB cost\n", 1 << GSHARE_SIZE, (1 << GSHARE_SIZE) * 2 / 8 / 1024);

    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << GSHARE_SIZE); i ++)
        gtable[i] = 0;


    brh_fetch = 0;
    brh_retire = 0;
}

void PredictorRunACycle() {
    // get info about what uops are processed at each pipeline stage
    const cbp3_cycle_activity_t *cycle_info = get_cycle_info();

    // make prediction at fetch stage
    for (int i = 0; i < cycle_info->num_fetch; i++) {
        uint32_t fe_ptr = cycle_info->fetch_q[i];
        const cbp3_uop_dynamic_t *uop = &fetch_entry(fe_ptr)->uop;

        if (runs == 0 && uop->type & IS_BR_CONDITIONAL) {
            // get prediction
            uint32_t gidx = (brh_fetch ^ uop->pc) & ((1 << GSHARE_SIZE) - 1);
            bool gpred = (gtable[gidx] >= 0);

            assert(report_pred(fe_ptr, false, gpred));
        }

        // update fetch branch history
        if (uop->type & IS_BR_CONDITIONAL)
            brh_fetch = (brh_fetch << 1) | (uop->br_taken ? 1 : 0);
        else if (uop_is_branch(uop->type))
            brh_fetch = (brh_fetch << 1) | 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cycle_info->num_retire; i++) {
        uint32_t rob_ptr = cycle_info->retire_q[i];
        const cbp3_uop_dynamic_t *uop = &rob_entry(rob_ptr)->uop;

        if (runs == 0 && uop->type & IS_BR_CONDITIONAL) {
            uint32_t gidx = (brh_retire ^ uop->pc) & ((1 << GSHARE_SIZE) - 1);

            // update predictor
            bool t = uop->br_taken;
            if (t && gtable[gidx] < 1)
                gtable[gidx] ++;
            else if (!t && gtable[gidx] > -2)
                gtable[gidx] --;


        // update retire branch history
        if (uop->type & IS_BR_CONDITIONAL)
            brh_retire = (brh_retire << 1) | (uop->br_taken ? 1 : 0);
        else if (uop_is_branch(uop->type))
            brh_retire = (brh_retire << 1) | 1;
    }
}

void PredictorRunEnd() {
    runs ++;
    if (runs < 1) // set rewind_marked to indicate that we want more runs
        rewind_marked = true;
}

void PredictorExit() {
    delete [] gtable;
}
```

I'm unsure which parts of this predictor are relevant to the "2-bit counter" component of this predictor.

Comment: The range of a 2-bit signed counter is `-2 .. 1`.  The range of a 3-bit signed counter is `-4 .. 3`, following the usual -2^(n-1) to 2^(n-1) - 1 rule for 2's complement.  It's not just an extra +1 at each end of the range.

Comment: I note that `gtable` is allocated as `1 << GSHARE_SIZE` `int8_t` -- for `GSHARE_SIZE = 18` that's 256K bytes -- not 64K ?  If `gtable` is supposed to be 64K bytes, then `1 << GSHARE_SIZE` appears to be the number of 2-bit counters which can be packed into 64K bytes -- so is the size in *counters*.  `GSHARE_SIZE = 17` would be consistent with `1 << GSHARE_SIZE` being the number of 4-bit counters which can be packed into 64K bytes -- or the number of 3-bit counters, wasting 2 bits per byte.

Comment: @ChrisHall: It's simulating a BPU in software, so I think the comment is about how much storage space a real BPU would need.  For 3-bit counters you'd modify that comment to 96kiB.  You presumably still want a power-of-2 number of counters.  (For data cache you can have set-associative caches that have 12 ways per set to get sizes like Ice Lake's 48kiB L1d caches, while still having indexing of a set be some low bits.  Not sure if BPUs tend to use set-associative addressing.  If so `(3<<16) * 3 bits / 8 bits-per-byte` is 72kiB, so a table size of `3<<16` could work...